# How to use a comparator when working with abstract classes?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, abstract-class, comparable

I've tried to use `compareTo` and implementing the interface of `Comparable` but I cannot find a way to compare two objects so that it returns an integer (-1 if the first object is smaller than the second one, 0 if they're equals and 1 if object 1 is greater than object 2). 
This is what I've tried:

```
public class MyArrayList<E> {

private Object[] array;
private int size;
private int capacity;

public MyArrayList() {
    this.capacity = 1000;
    this.array = new Object[capacity];
    this.size = 0;
}

public boolean add(E element) {
int i = 0;
while(element.compareTo(array[i]) > 0) {
    i++;
    }
this.set(i, element);
return true;
  }
}
```

I'm basically trying to sort my MyArrayList using a comparable. Do you have any idea what other ways I have to compare both objects?
Thanks!

Comment: You can require the `E` type to be comparable: change the class definition to: `public class MyArrayList<E extends Comparable<E>> { .. }` , so that `element.compareTo(..)` will call into the `E` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to only accept classes that implements the `Comparable` interface.

```
public class MyArrayList<E extends Comparable<E>> {
```

After that, you'll need to cast the parameter inside your `compareTo` call to `E`, since the `array` is of `Object` type.

```
public boolean add(E element) {
    int i = 0;
    while (element.compareTo((E) array[i]) > 0) {
        i++;
    }
    this.set(i, element);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Then i get other errors in my other classes such as: reviewArray = new MyArrayList<>();
                                     ^
    reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: Review
      lower bounds: Comparable<E>